# Afnetworking late response

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, afnetworking-2

I am new to AfNetworking, i want to get array after running my function but i always get crash as it loads data into array very late, is there any way to stop it till it loads all data into array?

```
   -(void) getModelDetails :(NSString*)brandName  completionHandler:(void (^)(id array))success
{

    NSString *brand = [brandName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://phablet-fix.com/mob/get-model-details.php?model=%@",brand];
    NSLog(@"%@",link);
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:link parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *returnedDealDict = responseObject ;
        NSArray *returnArray = [returnedDealDict objectForKey:@"modeldetails"];
        for(NSDictionary *dealDict in returnArray)
        {
            model = [[ModelDC alloc] init];
            model.modelID = [[dealDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
            model.model = [dealDict objectForKey:@"model"];
            model.mDeviceBrand = [dealDict objectForKey:@"device_brand"];
            model.mDeviceType = [dealDict objectForKey:@"device_type"];
            model.mProtectionPlanAvilable = [dealDict objectForKey:@"protection_plan_available"];
            model.mSilverPlan1year = [dealDict objectForKey:@"silver_plan_price_1year"];
            model.mSilverPlan2Year = [dealDict objectForKey:@"silver_plan_price_2year"];
            model.mSilverPlan3Year = [dealDict objectForKey:@"silver_plan_price_3year"];
            model.mGoldPlan1year = [dealDict objectForKey:@"gold_plan_price_1year"];
            model.mGoldPlan2year = [dealDict objectForKey:@"gold_plan_price_2year"];
            model.mGoldPlan3Year = [dealDict objectForKey:@"gold_plan_price_3year"];

            [dataArray addObject:model];

        }
        success(dataArray);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        if (dataArray.count == 0)
        {
            ALERT_VIEW(@"Please check your internet connection.");
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             ALERT_VIEW(@"Error occured while loading data.");
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         }];

}
```

and in my tableview i get zero data into my array

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    model = [planArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lblselectYourDevice.text = model.selectedModel;
    tblView.hidden = YES;
    modelDetailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self getModelDetails:model.selectedModel completionHandler:^(id array)
    {
        modelDetailArray = array;
    }];
    NSLog(@"%d",modelDetailArray.count);
    model = [[ModelDC alloc] init];
    model = [modelDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: What is the crash you get? You shouldn't make any thread wait, you should trigger an update when the process completes (which is how your code is already written).

Comment: i get crash index beyond limit

Comment: Where? Show the exception message and stack trace, and highlight the line that it happens on.

Comment: NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: see in my didselect row at index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work:

```
modelDetailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self getModelDetails:model.selectedModel completionHandler:^(id array)
{
    modelDetailArray = array;
}];
NSLog(@"%d",modelDetailArray.count);
model = [[ModelDC alloc] init];
model = [modelDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

because you are creating an empty array, asking for it to be populated with data and then immediately using it without waiting for the population to complete (or checking that the data you want was actually obtained).

Change to:

```
modelDetailArray = nil;

[self getModelDetails:model.selectedModel completionHandler:^(id array) {
    modelDetailArray = array;

    NSLog(@"%d", modelDetailArray.count);
    if (modelDetailArray.count > indexPath.row) {
        model = [modelDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // trigger the UI update or next piece of processing here
    } else {
        // deal with the error
    }
}];
```

Note that this also isn't creating empty objects that you aren't going to use.

Comment: my tableview is not empty ..what i have to do is to get parameter for next webservice when did select row is called .. after that it crashes

Comment: how can i put delay ..to wait for calling complete webservice?

Comment: You should not do that. Show an activity indicator if you want, but don't make the thread wait.

Comment: i know it will never come into this condition if (modelDetailArray.count > indexPath.row) {
        model = [modelDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // trigger the UI update or next piece of processing here
    }

Comment: Then either you are confused or you shouldn't be using `indexPath.row` there (which seems more likely as it is related to a different array than the one returned from your web call).

Comment: no i just want to enamurate.. ok i will do it using for loop